# How to implement click event or data point selection on apexCharts?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I am attempting to use the `apexCharts` javascript library and having trouble implementing the click event I have read the documentation but there's no clear example on how to implement it.

So far I have this code.

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'bar',
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        position: 'top', // top, center, bottom
                    },
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return val + "%";
                },
                offsetY: -20,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    colors: ["#304758"]
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Inflation',
                data: [2.3, 3.1, 4.0, 10.1, 4.0, 3.6, 3.2, 2.3, 1.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2]
            }],
            xaxis: {
                categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                position: 'top',
                labels: {
                    offsetY: -18,

                },
                axisBorder: {
                    show: false
                },
                axisTicks: {
                    show: false
                },
                crosshairs: {
                    fill: {
                        type: 'gradient',
                        gradient: {
                            colorFrom: '#D8E3F0',
                            colorTo: '#BED1E6',
                            stops: [0, 100],
                            opacityFrom: 0.4,
                            opacityTo: 0.5,
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: true,
                    offsetY: -35,

                }
            },
            fill: {
                gradient: {
                    enabled: false,
                    shade: 'light',
                    type: "horizontal",
                    shadeIntensity: 0.25,
                    gradientToColors: undefined,
                    inverseColors: true,
                    opacityFrom: 1,
                    opacityTo: 1,
                    stops: [50, 0, 100, 100]
                },
            },
            yaxis: {
                axisBorder: {
                    show: false
                },
                axisTicks: {
                    show: false,
                },
                labels: {
                    show: false,
                    formatter: function (val) {
                        return val + "%";
                    }
                }

            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly PCB Washout Occurrences, 2018',
                floating: true,
                offsetY: 320,
                align: 'center',
                style: {
                    color: '#444'
                }
            },

            active: {
                 allowMultipleDataPointsSelection: true,
            },

            events:{

                   dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, config){

                           console.log(event);
                       }

                }
        }

        var chart = new ApexCharts(
            document.querySelector("#chart"),
            options
        );

        chart.render();
```

I tried first the `click` event but found out that what I am looking for is the `dataPointSelection` method this is when a user clicks the column/bar chart it will return the event or data of the element, any idea how to implement this? any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your configuration for events is misplaced. You need to place `events` property inside `chart` property like this

```
chart: {
  events: {
    dataPointSelection: (event, chartContext, config) => {
      console.log(chartContext, config);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/junedchhipa/pen/rqQWjW) of your example.

Comment: How to route to a page on click event in apex charts??

Answer (score 10):

I think this is simply what you are looking for

```js
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    events: {
        dataPointSelection(event, chartContext, config) {
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex])
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex].name)
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex].data[config.dataPointIndex])
        }
    }
}
```

**if you need by the click**, this is better

```js
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    events: {
        click(event, chartContext, config) {
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex])
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex].name)
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex].data[config.dataPointIndex])
        }
    }
}
```

source [How to access value on dataPointSelection function of Apexchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486591/how-to-access-value-on-datapointselection-function-of-apexchart/)

documentation events https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/

Comment: For whatever reason I found that I had to use `config.w.config.series...`

Answer (score 1):

If you need the category clicked on:

```
events: {
              click(event, chartContext, config) {
                let ID = config.config.xaxis.categories[config.dataPointIndex];
                handleClick("Category Name" + ID);
              },
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
events: {
  dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, config) {

    alert (chartContext.w.globals.labels[config.dataPointIndex] )
    // The last parameter config contains additional information like `seriesIndex` and `dataPointIndex` for cartesian charts
  }
},
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)