# Return value from dataPointSelection event in Apexcharts

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I have a question related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52968984/9456495) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52972766/9456495) but they don't solve my question completely. I'm using vue and apexcharts and I would like to return a value or update a variable from an event. Is it possible to return something instead of printing it in the console?

Something like this:

```
    events: {
        dataPointSelection: function (event, chartContext, config) {
            this.active = this.series[config.seriesIndex];
        }
    }
```

The problem that I face is that "this" makes reference to the overall vue component and therefore "series" and "active" cannot be found.

Here is the code that gives me"TypeError: this.series is undefined" when I click on a point data. The series data I get from the parent component and it looks like this:

```
[{"name":"S-1","data":[[2.65,100], [6.67,100]]}, {"name":"S-2","data":[[0,50],[2.65,50]]}]
```

```
<script>
  import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts';

  export default {
    name: "myGraph",
    components: {
      apexchart: VueApexCharts,
    },
    props: {
      series: {}
    },
    data: () => ({
        active: undefined,
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            width: '100%',
            animations: {
              enabled: false
            },
            events: {
              dataPointSelection: function (event, chartContext, config) {
                this.active = this.series[config.seriesIndex];
              }
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            intersect: true,
            shared: false
          },
          markers: {size: 1},
      }
    }),
   }
 }
</script>
```

The idea is that on dataPointSelection, it should activate that serie in order to access later on other information that will be store in that object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to bind the event directly in the component

```
<apexchart type="bar" @dataPointSelection="dataPointSelectionHandler"></apexchart>

methods: {
  dataPointSelectionHandler(e, chartContext, config) {
    console.log(chartContext, config)
  }
}
```

Another way is to use ES6 arrow functions in your chart configuration

```
computed: {
  chartOptions: function() {
    return {
      chart: {
        events: {
          dataPointSelection: (e, chart, opts) => {
            // you can call Vue methods now as "this" will point to the Vue instance when you use ES6 arrow function
            this.VueDemoMethod();
          }
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simply what you are looking for

```js
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    events: {
        dataPointSelection(event, chartContext, config) {
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex])
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex].name)
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex].data[config.dataPointIndex])
        }
    }
}
```

**if you need by the click**, this is better

```js
chart: {
    type: 'area',
    events: {
        click(event, chartContext, config) {
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex])
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex].name)
            console.log(config.config.series[config.seriesIndex].data[config.dataPointIndex])
        }
    }
}
```

source [How to access value on dataPointSelection function of Apexchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486591/how-to-access-value-on-datapointselection-function-of-apexchart/)

documentation events https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/